# Convert date string from Google Calendars to date object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, calendar

I am still new to Ruby and am working on a project that involves users logging in through different calendar services, then displays it on a custom calendar on screen, for activity booking purposes.

I have been able to get the date in a String format. I am using the calendar I created after following the Railscast #231 to display the user's events. However, this calendar requires a `date` format to display the data.

I have tried everything I can, from `Time.parse("start")`, which gave me an error of:

```
"no implicit conversion of Date into String"
```

Thanks for any help in advance.I have a feeling I am going about this completely wrong. But I am so close to getting it to work I can taste it. haha

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a string to a date use `string.to_date`.

Examples:

```
Time.now.to_s
 => "2014-02-15 04:07:13 +0000"

Time.now.to_s.to_date
 => Sat, 15 Feb 2014
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted to do the opposite, and I just figured it out... Thank (non-denominational) God!... I'm new to StackOverflow.. what's the procedure here? Do I delete my question now?

Comment: Normally you do not delete your questions but you can tick or vote my or others' answer if it has been helpful to you.